# Mongodb accessing database

Tags: database, mongodb

i am trying to acces a mongodb database. Based on that tree 

`/var/lib/mongodb $ ls
admin.0  admin.ns  diagnostic.data  journal  local.0  local.1  local.ns  mongod.lock  mummer_alana.0  mummer_alana.ns  storage.bson`

The database iam trying to acces is store is the mummer_alana.0 but iam not able to see it on the shell.

```
 > show databases;
 admin  0.000GB
 local  0.000GB
```

Also i am pretty sure my dbpath is well configured

```
cat /etc/mongod.conf 
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb/
```

Cheers.

Comment: try: use mummer_alana

Comment: Already tried but the it's seems that it's empty. But when i "cat" the file a lot of data are in it.

Comment: What is the output of `db.version()` and `version()` in your `mongo` shell? How did you create the `mummer_alana` database for this server: was the data restored from backup, created via a MongoDB driver or tool, ...?